# How can I enforce certain strings in a MySQL table without using ENUMs?

Tags: mysql, string, enums

I used to use ENUMs in my previous projects.  For example, I'd have a column named `status` and have ENUM for `pending, success, fail`

However, I heard that ENUMs were bad, especially when growing and making changes in the future.

So, I've decided to leave ENUMs.  What's the best way to make sure the strings being inserted into MYSQL are only those certain strings?

Is there a database-way to do it, or do I have to do it at the application level?

Comment: Use [foreign key constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some options

- use another table with the defined strings. Then add a *Foreign key constraint* to that table where you need it
- *Check constraints* currently will be **ignored** from MySQL, so you can't use those
- use a `tinyint` and map this to your string in your logic if that is sufficient for you
- add insert and update *Triggers* that check the value before and throw an error when it is wrong

Comment: What do you mean "check constraints"? Can you elaborate on 2nd option?

Comment: In some DB engines (like SQL-Server) you can define a check constraint. A list of values that are valid for a column (defined during table definition). You can do that in MySQL too. But this setting will be ignored on runtime since it is not implemented yet in MySQL.

Comment: Is the 1st option the suggested one?

Comment: That is rather personal opinion. The clean way would be going with option one. Maybe I would go for a `tinyint` and handle it in my app. But that really depends on the number of possible values and if it is actually a problem that wrong entries arise.

Comment: ...but bear in mind that the `tinyint` option doesn't prevent invalid integers from being stored in the database - so it's really no different to enforcing a preset list of string values from within one's application code (i.e. the database is not really providing any help toward solving this problem whatsoever).  The fourth option either requires a separate table of valid values (same as first option, but less performant), or else the trigger must be dropped and recreated (requiring the database to be taken offline in order to ensure consistency) when changes occur.

Comment: I currently have 40 ENUMS throughout my database. Does that mean I have to create 40 new tables? (option 1)

Comment: If you want to add a foreign key constraint that only allows the specific values for a table, then yes.

Comment: There's no way I'm creating 40 extra tables! That's insane.  Can I have one table with 40 columns?

Comment: @juergend, I created one big table with 40 columns (all null).  That seems to work!